# how to access the azure web app application setting values in to typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

I had developed angular 2 application using visual studio 2015. then after I have published my angular2 web app into azure web app it's working everything fine but I am not able to get the azure web app application setting values into my typescript file of angular 2 web app.

Can you please share how to access the azure web app application setting values in to any typescript file.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the above issue as “to access the azure web app application setting values in to typescript file.”

I wrote the below lines of code in **Index.cshtml** for accessing the app setting values from **web.config** file.

```
    <script>
    window.config = {
        apiBaseUrl: '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"]',

    };
</script>
```

After that I wrote the below lines of code in **Services.ts**

```
import {Injectable, Inject, Optional, OpaqueToken} from '@angular/core';
export const API_BASE_URL = new OpaqueToken('API_BASE_URL');

@Injectable()
export class ApplicationClient {
private baseUrl: string = undefined; 

constructor(@Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : ""; 
  }
}
```

Next I have wrote the below lines of code **app.module.ts**

```
import { ApplicationClient,API_BASE_URL } from './shared/Services';
providers: [ { provide: API_BASE_URL, useValue: window['config']['apiBaseUrl'] }]
```

After that where ever you need to access the setting value, just import the path for **Services.ts** file in your typescript file like this below lines of code.

```
import { API_BASE_URL } from '../shared/Services';
 @Injectable()
export class writingService {
private _AppUrl = API_BASE_URL+'api/myApplication/';
}
```

-Pradeep

Comment: This will work only with .net right ? I have pure client side app with angular hosted in azure. Is there any way to access?