# Read Azure App Settings in Angular4 CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Angular4 web app, deployed on Azure. Now I want to deploy this app to other environments on Azure: one for testing, one for acceptance and one for production. Every environment has different API endpoints and may have other variables, like Application Insights. All those environments run Angular in production mode.

The way Angular advises you to do this, is by the Enviroment files (environment.test.ts, enviroment.acc.ts, environment.prod.ts). I could configure all the different API endpoints in those files, and run my build with `--prod` for production for example.

But that is not the way I want to do this. I want to use the exact same application package deployed to test for my acceptance environment, without rebuilding the project. In Visual Studio Online, this is also really simple to configure.

The point is: how can I make my API endpoints differ per environment in that way?

The way I want to do this, is by the App Settings in Azure. But Angular can't get to those environment variables because it's running on the client side. Node.js is running on serverside and could get those App Settings - but if that's the way I need to do it, how do I make Node.js (used in Angular4 CLI) to send those server variables to the client side? And what about performance impact for this solution?

How did you fix this problem for your Angular4 apps on Azure? Is it just impossible to fix this problem with the Azure App Settings?

Comment: Check here: [how to access the azure web app application setting values in to typescript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858448/how-to-access-the-azure-web-app-application-setting-values-in-to-typescript-file), and here: [angular 2 app on azure read app settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634154/angular-2-app-on-azure-read-app-settings).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But I cannot use the first link, because I dont have a index.cshtml file (i'm pure on clientside with my angular code). The second link just says it's impossible to do. I'm afraid it is... but I still hope there is something possible to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone with the same question: I didn't fix this problem the way I described above.

At the end, I did it the way Angular wants you to do it: so rebuild for dev, rebuild for acc and rebuild for prod. 
In Visual Studio Online, at build time, it builds and tests our code and it saves the uncompiled/unminified code. At release time, it builds en tests it again and releases it to the right environment with the right environment variables (`--prod` for example).

I don't think there is another way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty old school but it works! Although you can use branching or tag for this purpose instead of cloning the code to the package.
The best solution as you said is Azure app settings will be saved as environment variable so you should implement an API with node.js and share the variables you want. 
Of course there is an impact because of additional http call, but it's just one time at application start which is about max 5ms and depends on each program policy whether is impact or not.
Another option could be move the variables to the JSON file in the asset folder, and change it at deploy runtime with release pipeline. that's easier implementation but the disadvantage is you will have to use release variables instead of app settings and if you have config changes you will have to update the variable value first and redeploy it, although that works most of the times but sometimes you want to change just like a connection string and you will have to redeploy.